# Compactness : Notions are fine but for concept not sure.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've read brief topology part of my analysis book and came across the page of concept called compactness.

I've understood at least the definition of a set being compact (One shows $K$ is compact subset of space $X$ if for every open cover of $K$ there must be subcover of it which is finitely indexed), could prove some propositions like:

> "Any Compact set of metric spaces are closed",
>
> "If any finite subcollections of collection of compact sets $\{K_q\}$ is nonempty then intersection of all its elements is nonempty".

Thought I was going in right way and however, I really wasn't at all.
I know there are various proofs that tells $[0,1]$ is compact set and they are rigorously right.

But in order hand my intuition tells that :

for any $N$ positive integer,
$\{(-\frac1N,\frac1N),(0,\frac2N),(\frac1N,\frac3N),...,(1-\frac1N,1+\frac1N)\}$ covers our interval fine and it is infinite but one really can't expect
any subset of this to be covering $[0,1]$.

If we remove
$(\frac kN,k+\frac 2N)$ (where $k=0,1,\dots ,n-1$) from the list, it clearly won't cover point $k+\frac 1N$ of $[0,1]$  and no need to talk about when it is reduced to finite size. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi! This looks like a thoughtful and interesting question, but unfortunately, your notation is very difficult to read. Please learn some [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make this question (and your future questions) more legible, and in keeping with the site's standards.

Comment: Your cover is already finite; it has $N$ elements.

Comment: Well thanks for giving me comment hartkp but i was considering N to diverge to infinity and what would happen.

Comment: @BosarkNreuifedog What would happen is that you'd get a sequence of open covers, all of which are finite, but that grow unboundedly in number.

Comment: @TheoBendit.  N is constant in each of those terms.

Comment: That is what you should not do. You should not vary your open cover. Compactness says `"every open cover has its own finite subcover''. As soon as you say "let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover'' that cover is fixed for the duration of the proof. So your example should read ``let $N$ be any natural number and consider the cover ...'' that $N$ is then fixed.